# Why will parts of a rigid body roll on a rough inclined plane?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

If we have a rough inclined plane and a rigid body kept on it, the bottom most part of the body will rotate due to the torque produced by the frictional force. But why will any part rotate. If I am not wrong, gravity won't produce any torque in this case. (Also I can't understand why gravity won't be responsible for angular acceleration of any point size part of a rigid body in this case) .

I will be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the bottom most part of the body will rotate due to the torque produced by the frictional force

There are two errors here. Firstly, if the object is rigid then the whole body must rotate together, so saying that "the bottom most part of the body will rotate" is inaccurate, as it suggests that different parts of the body can rotate in different ways.

Secondly, when the body rotates it instantaneously pivots about a point that is in contact with the plane. The friction force also acts through this point. Therefore it is not friction that provides the torque that rotates the body. Instead, it is the body's weight. If the body's centre of mass is not vertically above the point that is in contact with the plane, then its weight exerts a torque about this point, and it is this torque that rotates the body.

Comment: If you consider the torque about the centre of mass of the body that torque is produced by the frictional force. So the system, the rigid body, is made to rotate due to the effect of all the forces acting on it, not just one in particular.